# C++ Can I pass a pointer to an object within its own function?

Tags: c++, class, object, pointers

For example,

I have a class foo with some member functions..

within some function say..

```
void foo::someFunction()
{

int pointer = ??????


}
```

How do I pass a pointer pointing to the object foo?

Can I do that? Or do I have to do it externally?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
foo* pointer = this;
```

Note that the pointer type should be `foo*` not `int`.

Answer (score 5):

The special pointer named `this` is available within (non-static) member functions for this purpose. However, it is not assignment compatible to `int`, but rather has type `foo *`.